# Images can't open in vs code

Tags: html, css, windows, image

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Code for the first time, and I'm practicing CSS in it. I downloaded an image from the web, copied and pasted it into a new folder, and opened that folder in Visual Studio Code. When I open my HTML file in the Mozilla Firefox web browser to see the result, only the text appears without any image. I've written the correct URL of that image. I've also received a notification on my Windows 11 PC that Windows Firewall has blocked some features of Visual Studio Code.

Hardware details:

> Windows 11 on a Dell Inspiron 15 5510

I tried reinstalling Visual Studio Code, but experienced the same problem.

Comment: As per Occam's razor, I'd say something's not quite right with the HTML you've written. Why don't you check that before fiddling with firewall or upgrading laptop drivers? Additionally, if you hit F12 in Firefox you'll get some awesome developer tools. Find the "Network" tab and check if it's trying to load pictures.